# How to pass directory to pass pygame icon?

Tags: python, pygame

I was trying to develop a basic python game 
I wonder how can I pass a directory to pygame's pygame.image.load() method
I tried passing directory to the method as a usual way...

```
import pygame as pg

#Intializing pygame
pg.init()

#Creating screen 
screen = pg.display.set_mode((800,600))

pg.display.set_caption("Mario Forever")
icon = pg.image.load('/resources/images/logo.png')
pg.display.set_icon(icon)
#Creating interrupt for exiting game in future
running = True

#Game quit event listener
while running:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
```

But I am encountering an error

```
icon = pg.image.load('/resources/images/logo.png')
pygame.error: Couldn't open /resources/images/logo.png
```

Please suggest me where I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Your path starts with a /. Is it an absolute path?

Comment: @Mace frankly I didn't understand what are you trying to ask. But as far I understood, no the given path is not absolute, this path exists in the same directory where the code is saved. Still, I tried adding the absolute path to the method but the error was the same.

Comment: What OS are you on? In windows starting with a / as /resources/images/logo.png means the root of your harddisk. Without / like resources/images/logo.png is the directory relative to your project directory.

Comment: @Mace can you put your last comment as an answer, thanks that solved my issue. Let me flag it as answer.

Comment: Done. I'm glad it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your path '/resources/images/logo.png' starts with a /. That means that the path starts at the root directory of your harddisk.

When you ommit the first / the directory path 'resources/images/logo.png' is relative to your project directory.